# Behavior of Smart Pointer When Casting a shared_ptr<void> to a shared_ptr<type>

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, shared-ptr

I am currently working on a project that requires me to have a vector storing pointers to objects of the same class but with different template values. I want to use shared_ptrs for reasons that I won't get too deep into (mainly that if I want to share a Column between two ColumnLists).

I need to be able to return a casted pointer from a function (as seen below).

So here is a very simplified version:

```
template <typename ColType>
class Column {
    std::vector<ColType>;
};

template <typename ...TypesOfColumns>
class ColumnList {

private:
    std::vector< std::shared_ptr<void> > columnsVector;  
    /* Needs to have a vector storing pointers to multiple Columns
       all with different template values */

public:
    template <typename ReturnType> std::shared_ptr<ReturnType> GetPointer(int index)
    {
        return std::static_pointer_cast<ReturnType>(columnsVector.at(index));
    };

};
```

I am wondering if I am getting to some type of undefined behavior here?  Will it work as I am hoping: will returning the casted type just add one to the Strong Reference Counter of the void pointer?  Can one be deleted before the other one is? Am I risking a memory leak where one gets deleted and the other does not (I doubt this one to be the case)?

As always, thanks for all of the help!!!

Comment: [codereview.se]

Comment: @cpplearner I disagree. "This code works, can I make it better" is suited to CR. "This code appears to work, but does it really" is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

static_pointer_cast follows the same rules that static_cast does. It is legal to downcast a pointer-to-base to a pointer-to-derived as long as `derived` derives from `base`. As long as you are sure that `columnsVector.at(index)` contains a `shared_ptr<ReturnType>` (that is, contains a `shared_ptr<void>` that originated as a `shared_ptr<ReturnType>`), what you are doing is legal. If you don't know for sure, you should use dynamic_pointer_cast.

Further, regarding memory, the output of static_pointer_cast shares the same underlying control block as the input, so it's safe that way too. Even if the input were to be deleted first, the output would remain a legal owner of the shared resource, and vice-versa.

Comment: Awesome, the second graph was really helpful!  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

IMO much better would be having an abstract column as the base class for the template:

```
struct AbstractColumn {
    virtual ~AbstractColumn() {}
    ...
};

template<typename Type>
struct Column : AbstractColumn {
    std::vector<Type> data;
};
```

That would provide a place where to put generic methods (e.g. conversion to string, parsing from string etc.) and will also allow you to use pointers to the base class instead of pointers to `void`.

Comment: I would explicitely move (or at least add) virtual destructor to `AbstractColumn`

Comment: @Zereges: actually it was meant to be there indeed, fixed.